# SELECT row of last update with same value

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

We have this table that keeps inserting values of Inrunning field which is a number.. There are multple mistakenly insert. I want to get the row where the first insert happened with duplicate value. In this case 5000 value inserted 3 times in matter of minutes. So i want to get the value first inserted which is Row 3.

[image]

Comment: What Oracle database version do you have? Run `select banner from v$version` if you don't know, and report the full version number, such as 11.2.0.3.0 or 12.2.0.1.0. Different solutions are available in different versions - the newer the version, the better the tools that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `analytical` function here as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*, 
       Sum(case when inrunningdelay_1 = leadval then 1 end)
           over (partition by writer order by wrriten_1) as sm
 from
(Select t.*,
        lead(inrunningdelay_1) over (partition by writer order by wrriten_1) as leadval
from your_table t) t)
Where sm = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you're using `Oracle DB 12c+`, then you can use with no need to use an extra subquery through `FETCH` clause with `1 ROW ONLY` option together with `ORDER BY` clause including 
>   `LEAD()` analytic function  as
>
> `LEAD(inrunningdelay_1) OVER ( PARTITION BY writer ORDER BY written_1 )`
>
> starting from the value `zero` for
>
> `ABS( inrunningdelay_1 - LEAD(inrunningdelay_1) OVER ( PARTITION BY writer ORDER BY written_1 ) )`
>
> through use of absolute value for the difference

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM t   
 ORDER BY ABS( inrunningdelay_1 - LEAD(inrunningdelay_1) 
                                  OVER ( ORDER BY written_1 ) )
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fd164e22e7401863deed22776ccafd72)</kbd>

**Update :** `PARTITION BY writer` would be redundant within the above case, since that would work **only** for one writer as Tejash mentioned. For multiple writers, consider the below Select statement :

```
WITH t2 AS
(
  SELECT t.*, 
         ABS( inrunningdelay_1 - LEAD(inrunningdelay_1) 
             OVER ( PARTITION BY writer ORDER BY written_1 ) ) as ld            
    FROM t      
   ORDER BY writer, ld, written_1   
)
SELECT written_1, writer, inrunningdelay_1  
  FROM t2  
 ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER  ( PARTITION BY writer ORDER BY ld )
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

where you'd filter out the `zero` returned values only, and then would pick **only** the **first** returned ones **for each writers** by contribution of `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function within the deepest `ORDER BY` clause :

<kbd>[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7723404ac0df0fdb2e2bb2cbc930fe1d)</kbd>

Comment: This will work for only 1 writer. OP will not be able to find all such occurance using this for all the writers

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . Is that really new in Oracle 12C?  Other analytic functions are permitted in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right, of course. I rearranged the order of the sentences to express that I meant `FETCH` clause for Oracle 12+.